# Create table with auto increment field

Tags: mysql

I try this :

```
create table booktable(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Name varchar(10), BorrowStatus varchar(5),Date varchar(10) );
```

But it has error!

I want to create a table with this columns:
`ID` , `Name` , `BorrowStatus` , `Date`

Comment: "But it has error!" - it would help if you told us what the error is.

Comment: When you get that sorted change Date or DateD to a date type, otherwise you'll be on here asking for more help soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` is reserved word then you can't use it as field name.

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` field must be defined as key either unique or primary.

Comment: Now: `incorrect table definition: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your AUTO_INCREMENT column as a key field. The error message tells you this.

Try:

```
create table booktable(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, Name varchar(10), BorrowStatus varchar(5),Date varchar(10) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example to create an auto inceremented field as the primary key of your table

```
  CREATE TABLE example_autoincrement (
             id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
             data VARCHAR(100)
           );
```